# Access windows Authenticated Web API through Angular 2 without login prompt

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, windows-authentication

I have already developed front-end application in Angular2 and back-end in ASP.net web APIs. I had used Windows authentication as enabled because I want to detect requesting user. Both applications are hosted in IIS server(Windows Server 2012).
When I load angular app it load login prompt and when give correct user credentials data loading happen correctly.
But I want to know a way to load them without login prompt, authenticate automatically.

This is the way I detect request user in web APIs.

```
string user = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"]; //Get the current user...
userID = user.Split('\\')[1];
```

This is a sample TS script send request to Windows Authenticated Web APIs from Angular Services.

```
getPersonalInfo(): Observable<IPersonalInfo> {
        return this._http.get(localStorage.getItem('WebApiURL') +"api/PersonalInfo/" , { withCredentials: true })
            .map((response: Response) => <IPersonalInfo>response.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

When restart the browser this login ask every time.

I want to access them with out this login...

[image]

Comment: This means you need to enable windows authentication in your angular 2 application right ?

Comment: yep. But enabling win authentication in angular app also ask another login prompt. However I want to recognize requesting user through URL.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I am using angular 6 for frontend and flask(python) as the web api. I have enabled windows authentication and it works fine. But I need to find the username somehow.

Comment: Don't you try the following solution. That's the way I solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this login prompt occurs because there is communication between two technologies (ASP.net & Angular 2) by passing windows windows credentials. So it need shake-hand authentication when call windows authenticated API.

I was lucky to find a solution by changing privacy settings through browser. So I got ability to call API's without login prompt.

Here is the way to do that.

Settings -> Open Proxy settings -> Privacy ->Sites

[image: Screenshot is here...]

In here you can add domain where your back-end APIs are already hosted as in example.
After that it take as trusted domain and further more there is no any login prompt accruing.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent a lot of time on this, and I'm not sure it can be done. If you enable Anon Access then the [Authorisation] on the controllers works fine. But you can't detect the username.

If you disable the Anon Access then you can obtain the username NETWORK//USERNAME but if you access a method with the [Authorize] attribute then you get the popup dialog you have got.

I really don't want to go back to a username/password solution but it is looking like I am going to have to.